# how to find smallest value of td :contains(textbox) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How do I get smallest value of the textbox using jquery?
rows means trs which contain multiple tds & tds in turn contains textboxes I want to find the smallest value of each tr

```
 $.each(rows, function () {
             $(this).find("input[type='text']") //find smallest value of the textbox
    });
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Are the values numeric? If not, what makes a value "big" or "small?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Here's what I did:

```
$.each(rows, function () {
    var sorted = $(this).find("input[type='text']").sort(
        function(a, b) { return a.value - b.value }
    );
    var lowest = sorted[0].value;
});
```

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle of the code above: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/rNc4p/5/

Comment: thanks but i want the <b>textbox</b> which contains smallest value

Comment: The textbox with the lowest value is `sorted[0]`.

Answer (score 4):

You can build an array of the smallest `<input>` values in each `<tr>` using `.map()`. Assuming you want to interpret each value as a number:

```
var minValues = $(rows).map(function ()
{
    var rowVals = $(this).find('input:text').map(function ()
    {
        return Number($(this).val());
    }).get();

    return Math.min.apply(null, rowVals);
}).get();
```

API docs:

- [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map)
- [`:text` selector](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/)
- [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val)
- [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)
- [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

---

If you don't need to use the array as a whole, and just iterate over the minimum values:

```
$(rows).each(function ()
{
    var rowVals = $(this).find('input:text').map(function ()
    {
        return Number($(this).val());
    }).get();

    var min = Math.min.apply(null, rowVals);

    // do stuff with min
})
```

Comment: thanks but i want the <b>textbox</b> which contains smallest value

Comment: @Ulhas is it really such a stretch to change one selector?